# Error trapping in python when Houghlines does not detect any lines

Tags: python, opencv

I have been looking at the `python binding` of `opencv` to create a line following robot , just to see if it is possible.

My code is based on one of many examples I have found on the web.
Occasionally no lines are detected and my program crashes.

When it crashes, `Houghlines` returns a `type NoneType`, see lines in the snippet below. 
I have come across lots of discussion on the web about using (or not) checking for `type(lines)==NoneType`, is instance etc. The preferred solution seems to be to use a `try/except` construct.

In the end I have used a `try/except` construct on a new variable

```
numLines=lines.size
```

This approach works, my program no longer crashes.

```
def detectLines(image):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize=3)
    lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200)
    try:
        # way of determining if lines have been detected
        numLines = lines.size
        modifedImage=drawLines(image,lines)
        key = showImage(modifedImage)
    except:
        key = 0
    return key
```

I am relatively new to Python, is my approach the "python" way, is there a better approach?

Comment: This is probably a bit of an opinion based question. IMHO this is not a good solution -- this is not an unexpected scenario, and it can be handled cleanly and explicitly by a simple `if lines:`. You probably want to have some specific handling for the "no lines" case. As written, the intent is far from clear. The catch-all will also eat up any other potential errors silently. TBH that function seems to need refactoring -- it's called `detectLines`, but it shows an image when lines found and returns a keycode. [Too much surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) ;)

Comment: I never thought of just testing "if lines:", I will try that. I agree the function needs refactoring.